# How do I set a maximum allowed bottom line that can be reached of a position absolute element

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Im developing a product label plugin for WordPress and I have the following already done:
[image]

Here's the output code of what you're seeing on the image:

```
<a href="https://localhost/woo-metal/product/test-3/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">

  <div class="wb_badge-container">
    <span class="wb_badge wb_badge-rounded wb_badge-topright" style="background-color:#dd3333;color:#ffffff;">TEST</span>
  </div>

  <img src="https://localhost/woo-metal/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-placeholder.png" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" alt="Placeholder" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="450" height="450">
  
  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Test 3</h2>
  
  <span class="price">

    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.00
      </bdi>
    </span>

  </span>

</a>
```

The badge have the following CSS:

```
// ....
.wb_badge {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 12px;
    min-width: 15px;
    min-height: 15px;
    font-size: 12.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-word;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.wb_badge-topleft {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wb_badge-topright {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.wb_badge-bottomleft {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wb_badge-bottomright {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
// ....
```

I want to achieve when the badge have a bottomleft or bottomright position to be placed AT THE END OF THE PRODUCT IMAGE and not below. Currently with my CSS I can achieve being placed at the very bottom next to the Add to cart button. I tried adding position relative to some element to set a break point of the positions but it didn't worked. Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: sorry could you please clarify which element are you trying to place and where? I can't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

The only way can you do this with CSS (without using JavaScript), is to change your HTML markup. You'll need to wrap the `img` in an element and put your badge element *inside* of that:

```css
.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /* remove this line in your real code. testing only */
}

.wb_badge {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px;
  min-width: 15px;
  min-height: 15px;
  font-size: 12.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-word;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.wb_badge-topleft {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wb_badge-topright {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.wb_badge-bottomleft {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.wb_badge-bottomright {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://localhost/woo-metal/product/test-3/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="wb_badge-container">
      <span class="wb_badge wb_badge-rounded wb_badge-bottomright" style="background-color:#dd3333;color:#ffffff;">TEST</span>
    </div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/400" class="woocommerce-placeholder wp-post-image" alt="Placeholder" decoding="async" loading="lazy" width="450" height="450">
  </div>

  <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">Test 3</h2>

  <span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi>
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>0.00
    </bdi>
    </span>
  </span>

</a>
```

Comment: Okay, any suggestions on how to override the default WC shop loop with my custom plugin?

Comment: That is beyond the scope of the original question. If this answer addresses the current question, you can either upvote it or mark as accepted. Then, you can open a new question with this code and ask how to override the default template in WC. It's far more helpful to future visitors.